# Reducir tamaño de un archivo WAV

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy utilizando un editor de audio de: https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist. Funciona correctamente y exporta el archivo de audio esperado. Sin embargo el audio por ser formato wav, es un poco pesado y ya con algunos minutos se van unos cuantos MegaBytes.

Viendo un poco el proyecto revisé el archivo `waveform-playlist.var.js` y me encontré con las funciones `exportWAV(type)`, `interleave(inputL, inputR)` y `encodeWAV(samples)`

Intente modificar la función `interleave`, dejando un solo canal, o tomando un promedio entre ambos, pero el sonido se deforma.

¿Hay alguna forma de reducir el tamaño del wav, disminuyendo un poco la calidad del audio, o algo por el estilo ?

Agredesco su ayuda! :)

```
  function encodeWAV(samples) {
    var mono = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : false;

    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
    var view = new DataView(buffer);

    /* RIFF identifier */
    writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
    /* file length */
    view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
    /* RIFF type */
    writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
    /* format chunk identifier */
    writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
    /* format chunk length */
    view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
    /* sample format (raw) */
    view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
    /* channel count */
    view.setUint16(22, mono ? 1 : 2, true);
    /* sample rate */
    view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
    /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
    view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
    /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
    view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
    /* bits per sample */
    view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
    /* data chunk identifier */
    writeString(view, 36, 'data');
    /* data chunk length */
    view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

    floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

    return view;
  }

  function interleave(inputL, inputR) {

    var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
    var result = new Float32Array(length);

    var index = 0;
    var inputIndex = 0;

    while (index < length) {
      result[index += 1] = inputL[inputIndex];
      result[index += 1] = inputR[inputIndex];
      inputIndex += 1;
    }

    return result;
  }

  function exportWAV(type) {
    var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
    var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
    var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
    var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
    var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

    postMessage(audioBlob);
  }
```

Comment: Podrías usar el sistema de tickets de github para informar de que deseas la mejora en la exportación en https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist/issues

Answer (score 1):

Nunca jamás podrás reducir el tamaño de un WAV (conservando toda su calidad) y menos utilizando código. La única manera de convertir a WAV es con un archivo de audio con baja calidad. El sonido en WAV es exactamente como está grabado ó bien a tiempo real o convertido desde otro formato tipo mp3, ogg, etc. Mi sugerencia es que cuando realices la conversión, el archivo a convertir esté a una calidad media/aceptable para que el WAV pese menos. Realiza pruebas y verás. Un saludo!!!

Comment: He utilizado la librería lame.js, que transformar el buffer de audio a mp3. La función que utiliza para ello toma como parámetros el bufferaudio, samplerate y kbps. El archivo resulta es aproximadamente de 1MB por cada minuto. Trate de disminuir los Kbps entre 32 a 128. Pero no hay diferencia en el peso del archivo.

Comment: Intentalo off line con un editor de audio tipo SoundForge o si lo prefieres, tienes uno similar y gratuito, Audacity. Mi consejo es que si deseas que baje de megas el WAV con calidad razonable, convierte un mp3 mínimo a 128/192 kbps para que compruebes la diferencia.

Comment: con lamejs he logrado generar el mp3 a 128 Kbps. Si reduce el tamaño drásticamente.

Comment: El [formato de contenedor de audio WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Comparison_of_coding_schemes) soporta múltiples códecs o esquemas de codificación como µ-Law, ADPCM, GSM, MP3, etc y no sólo los formatos PCM (RAW) 8 y 16 bits de los que habla @JaimeVinuesa. El problema es que en ese proyecto [está fijado](https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist/issues/75) en código tanto la frecuencia, tamaño de muestra y formato de exportación.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único viable es convertirlo a otro formato, como m4A y usar el audio M4A, pero si quieres usar WAV sí o sí, puedes convertirlo y luego realizar la conversión de nuevo a costa de perder un poco de calidad de audio, depende del uso del audio, si necesita ser de alta fidelidad o no.